# Can a factorial have an exponent

Tags: factorial

can you do $(4!)^4$ or do you have to do $4! \times 4$, I have looked on google but can't find anything to prove or disprove if it's possible.

Comment: why not? (4!)^4 = (4 x 3 x 2 x 1)^4

Comment: Sure, 4! is just a number

Comment: Um... what do you mean?  $(4^4) = 256$ so $4^4! = 256!$.  $4! = 24$ so $(4!)^4 = 24^4$.  $((4!)!)!)!) = .... $ well, it's doable (but large).  These are just numbers.  We could define $3!^3$ to mean $((3!)!)! = (6!)! = 720! = ...$ but that would be us creating a (consistant and well-defined) operation.  Which we are allowed to do!

Comment: Do you mean $(4!)^4$, or do you have something more exotic in mind like $4(!^4)$?

Comment: You can do whatever you want! As long as it's clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here is a shot at it:

$4!$ is just a number -- specifically, it's the number $24$.  So $(4!)^4$ is exactly the same thing as $24^4$, which is $331,776$.

Comment: Thank you this answers my question. This might sound stupid but why do you have to put parenthesis around 4! ?

Comment: For clarity.  Otherwise it's not always clear what you mean.

Comment: For example, suppose you wanted to use the notation $4(!^4)$ to mean $4!!!!$, i.e. $(((4!)!)!)!$. That would be something completely different (and much larger.)

Comment: That notation is not standard, but there's no reason in a particular context you couldn't establish it as a notational convention and then use it.  In that case you would need to distinguish between $(4!)^4$ and $4(!^4)$.

Comment: Thank you again this does really help me. Have a nice day.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: If you wrote $4!^4$ I image 16% of the mathematicians would think you meant $(4!)^4$ and thin it is fine I imagine 35% of the mathematicians would think you meant $(4!)^4$ but warn you "it looks funny".  12% would think you meant $(((4!)!)!)!$ and praise your cleverness.  1% would think you meant $(4^4)!$ and the other 99% of the mathematicians would laugh at this 1 percent.  And the other 36% will have no idea what you are talking about.  (Numbers totally pulled out of thin air.)

Comment: But @fleablood please note that the OP did *not* write $4!^4$.  He or she wrote 4!^4, all inline.  With the raised exponent it is (I think) much less ambiguous. In any case my point was just that parentheses help with readability, whether the expression is inline or formatted.

Comment: @fleablood "$\text{41% of all statistics are made up on the spot,}$" right?

Comment: Parenthesis definitely add clarity.  But the point is... any manipulation or interpretation is doable.  They are just numbers after all.